# Combining Likelihood from different experiment

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, pooling

Lets say I have the results of experiment and wanted to determine the one unknown parameter (theta) using likelihood. The log likelihood for 3 different experiments are as follow:

Experiment 1 : 23 log theta + 34 log (1-theta) + 5 log (theta+2)

Experiment 2 : 12 log theta + 10 log (1-theta)

Experiment 3 : 15 log theta + 13 log (1-theta)

is it possible to combine the result of three experiments to infer single maximum likelihood for theta? How could I accomplish that and what's are the requirement?

Sorry, perhaps this is a very simple question, but I am really newbie in learning about likelihood.

Comment: If experiments are independent, you should be able to multiply the likelihoods, i.e. add the log-likelihoods

Answer (score 1):

If experiments are independent you should just multiply the likelihoods, that is, add the loglikelihoods.  If experiments are not independent, we would need more details.  However, even if experiments are not independent, adding the loglikelihoods would give a composite likelihood.